# google cloud secret management

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

im comming here with some basic question how is the best way to import secrets from google cloud management with using google cloud run or is there any chance to import to application.yaml as variable ? or it is only available for kubernetes ? Im using spring boot java application. I am quite new to gcp so im open on any effective ideas, thanks.

Comment: Stack overflow is intended to help solve coding issues. Google's documentation is extensive. I encourage you to read it: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @DazWilkin you can try to do a reading and [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/create-secret) on how you can apply Google Cloud Secret Manager. The link shared includes [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/best-practices).

Google provides a documentation where you can apply and practice Secret Manager to Cloud Run and GKE. In addition to that Google documentation provides codes and commands for different sources. For [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#yaml) and for [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret#yaml-file).